# retrieve data from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I have these four table assume that ring table consist of five fields(jewelry_id,ring_id,image,type,brand_id)

Note that brand table have its foreign key in ring table and ring and style both have foreign keys in ring_style table. now i want to retrieve the following data from these four table
(ring_id, image,type, brand,style) but did't get the query any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ring_id, image, type,
    brand,
    style
FROM      ring
LEFT JOIN brand ON ring.brand_id = brand.brand_id
LEFT JOIN ring_style ON ring.jewelry_id = ring_style.jewelry_id
     LEFT JOIN style ON ring_style.style_id = style.style_id
```

Note that each ring will appear one or more times. It will appear more than one time when there is more than one `ring_style` record for the ring.

Answer (score 2):

You just join each table using the columns that relate them.

```
SELECT
  ring.ring_id,
  style.image,
  ring.type,
  brand.brand,
  style.style
FROM
  brand
INNER JOIN
  ring
ON
  brand.brand_id = ring.brand_id
INNER JOIN
  ring_style
ON
  ring.jewelry_id = ring_style.jewelry_id
INNER JOIN
  style
ON
  ring_style.style_id = style.style_id
```

Comment: i have two type for ring(wedding,engagement) where should i check the type for same situation. i.e if i want to check the same record against wedding then how can i update the query

Comment: Add `WHERE ring.type = 'wedding'` to your query?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the SQL command `JOIN`:

An example to get the information from ring and brand with one query use:

```
SELECT * FROM ring 
JOIN brand ON ring.brand_id = brand.brand_id;
WHERE ring.jewelry_id = 123456
```

Use multiple JOIN in one query to get multiple tables connected in one query.